# How to change JSON format to expected format in PHP

Tags: php, json

How to change JSON format to expected format

## JSON

```
[{
    "storenm": "S1",
    "FA_SOH": "20964",
    "FA_CY_QTY": "15",
    "FA_CT_QTY": "44497"
},
{
    "storenm": "S2",
    "FA_SOH": "1096",
    "FA_CY_QTY": "2",
    "FA_CT_QTY": "7501"
}];
```

## Expected

```
[['S1',
'20964',
'15',
'44497'],
['S2',
'1096',
'2',
'7501']];
```

Comment: what will receive the json data?

Comment: @gert JavaScript variable will receive

Answer (score -1):

You can use [json_decode($json,true)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to get an an array, then use [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to remove the keys and then transform it back to json with [json_encode($newarray)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)